# Credit card match with number + expire and CVV

Tags: regex

Hi i want regex that match credit card with NUMBER+EXPIRE+CVV in one regex line
what I done

1. **`\d{4}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}`**

   ```
        credit card number MATCH
   ```
2. **`(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/?([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})`**

   ```
        EXPIRE MATCH
   ```
3. **`[0-9]{3}$`**

   ```
        CVV MATCH
   ```

I need credit card match only if match like this

(!chk) beginning word  (n)  credit card number (M)  month   (y)  year  (X) cvv

1. !chk nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn mmyy xxx

or

1. !chk nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn mm|yy xxx

or

1. !chk nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn mm/yy xxx

or

1. !chk nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn mm\yy xxx

or

1. !chk nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn mmyyyy xxx

Comment: Please specify what language you are working in.

Answer (score 1):

Try `!chk \d{16} (?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])[\/\\|]?(?:[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2}) \d{3}`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XCcBMJ/1)